# How to fetch the JSON data in flutter application?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-pageview

I have below JSON data fetched from server, which I need to fetch and configure in pageviewbuilder as well as listview builder in flutter application.

Listview builder(vertical scroll) is nested in Pageview builder(horizontal scroll), this I already configured

Things To be Display are like this

> Page   ----------  Order Items
>
> Order 16      >>  Order 16, item 1        , Order 16 item 2
>
> Order 18     >>   Order 18, item 1 ,       Order 18 item 2   ,    order 18
> item 3

I am new to the learning of JSON in flutter, please guide me how should I fetch the data and use to for the configuration of the above as required.

```
{
    "error": "false",
    "content": [
        {
            "comp_code": "4",
            "comp_name": "KMT OVERSEAS",
            "order_no": "16",
            "soh_pk": "23660",
            "order_items": [
                {
                    "comp_code": "4",
                    "comp_name": "KMT OVERSEAS",
                    "order_no": "16",
                    "sod_pk": "31689",
                },
                {
                    "comp_code": "4",
                    "comp_name": "KMT OVERSEAS",
                    "order_no": "16",
                    "sod_pk": "31688",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "comp_code": "4",
            "comp_name": "KMT OVERSEAS",
            "order_no": "18",
            "soh_pk": "23702",
            "order_items": [
                {
                    "comp_code": "4",
                    "comp_name": "KMT OVERSEAS",
                    "order_no": "18",
                    "sod_pk": "31749",
                },
                {
                    "comp_code": "4",
                    "comp_name": "KMT OVERSEAS",
                    "order_no": "18",
                    "sod_pk": "31742",

                },
                {
                    "comp_code": "4",
                    "comp_name": "KMT OVERSEAS",
                    "order_no": "18",
                    "sod_pk": "31743",
                },
               
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For fetch JSON from a server:

1. Add the Http package.
2. Make a network request using the Http package.
3. Convert the response into a list
4. Move this work to a separate isolate.

For more info check out [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) link

Answer (score 1):

You have to Follow the following steps and customize the given code to your own:

**1** Place this plugin in pubspec.yaml file   `http: ^0.12.0+4`

**2** import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; ///http i am using below you can change it

**3** build a function to fetch data:

```
  Future<Map> getNews() async {
  String apiurl = "https://your url/";
  http.Response response = await http.get(apiurl);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

**4** delare a Map variable

```
Map data;
```

**5** call the funtion inside of async method like:

```
// Future<void> main() async {} you can call inside  initstate or any custom function 
 data = await getNews();
```

now your json data is inside of `data`, you can use it any way as you want.
**6** used inside your listview.builder like following

```
new Center(
        child: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
              return new ListTile(
//here posts and title are json variables that are in json file
                title: new Text("${data["posts"][position]["title"]}"),
                subtitle: new Text(
                  parseHtmlString("${data["posts"][position]["content"]}"),
                  maxLines: 18,
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
```

Comment: Hey Qasim, where exactly I need to call `data = await getNews();`  because I called in it a async method and that method is called in `initState()` and i am getting `data` as null, please provide a guidance

Comment: you can call it in main function, it will works fine, and also declare Map data as a project level global variable. and you can use 'data' every where as you want in your project. @VickySingh

Comment: you can check 'data' as by printing on Console. to ensure that it is null or not @VickySingh

Comment: I called it in the main function, and it comes out to be null

Comment: call it in main(), then use debugprint('$data'); in next line and check , what is output?

Comment: you mean to call it in `void initState()`?

Comment: paste your main.dart file code here i will guide you