# how can i get data from API using flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, http

I am new to flutter , I am creating an app and want to integrate JSON API in my application for Quran , Qibla and all things like this.
Kindly suggest me best API for this requirement and how i will be able to integrate this API in my App?

```
  Future<Map> getNews() async {
  String apiurl = "https://your url/";
  http.Response response = await http.get(apiurl);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Comment: kindly read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626242/how-to-fetch-the-json-data-in-flutter-application/63628533#63628533

Comment: How can i get API URL

Comment: Which API are you using ? I can help you find the API Url if you share the name of the API or any website where you might have found it

Comment: i need api of ahadees sunni and fiqh books of muslims

Answer (score 0):

You can get required API URLs by visiting relevant platforms like [Al Quran](https://alquran.cloud/) for Quran. Here is an [example](http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran/quran-uthmani) URL for all the Surah in Quran. For Ahadith, you can get APIs from [Sunah.com](https://sunnah.com/). Also, see a [Sample App](https://flutterawesome.com/islamic-app-with-complete-quran-prayer-time-api-hadith-qibla-direction/) for what you are trying to create. You'll need to google stuff for each of your requirements and features.